# Background cardView shape not defined

Tags: android, android-cardview

I defined a CardView that should look similar to the image below, but there is also a shape behind it that has not been defined (red arrows).
I know that CardView is responsible for the problem, because if you replace it with a LinearLayout there is no problem.
Using the Layout Inspector I don't see this shape either, does anyone know if it is a specification of the cardView that is making the unwanted shape appear?

[image: Cardview image]

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/Transparent"
        app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
        app:cardCornerRadius="16dp"
        app:cardElevation="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
```

**update:**
Setting an elevation value to a high value, for example 128dp, the problem does not arise. It's not the ideal solution, but it solves

Comment: Please provide the complete layout code.

Answer (score 0):

You could create this corner rounded background by shape. Example:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle"
    android:tint="@color/base_color">

    <corners android:radius="@dimen/corners_radius" />
</shape>
```

I'm not 100 % sure but I think it caused by elevation.

Comment: and set as the background, right? Like this android:background="@drawable/name"

Comment: You are right. Anyway if its elevation issue you can try to remove it or change color of shadow.